# .net chooses the wrong root folder

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

If I'm using the tilde-character to start from the root in a link, for example in an image like this:
"~/images/image.jpg"
my browser tries to link to "default.aspx/images/image.jpg"
why?

Comment: How are you mapping that path?

Comment: Can you post your code where you are setting the path with the tilde?

Comment: sure, here is the actual code:         .deleteIcon {
             height:20px; width:20px; background:url(~/Images/imported/glyphicons-halflings.png)
        }

Comment: Im also using a FormsAuthentication wich adds "default.aspx/" before the url to my querystring, so the problem is not only with css or images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config, set:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms ... defaultUrl="~/" ... />
</authentication>
```

**Reminder:**

- `/` - Site root
- `~/` - Root directory of the application

The difference is that if you site is:

```
http://example.com
```

And you have an application `myapp` on:

```
http://example.com/mydir/myapp
```

`/` will return the root of the site (`http://example.com`),

`~/` will return the root of the application (`http://example.com/mydir/`).

Comment: sorry, im at vacation... Yes, it did. Thank you very much!